# Asymptote of graph $\ln (3x+2)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How to sketch the graph of $\ln (3x+2)$

I know that the x intercept is $\frac{-1}{3}$ and y intercept is $0.7$ . But for a logarithm graph, the asymptote of the graph is $x=$ something. For example, I know that the graph of $\ln (x-2)$ has an asymptote at $x=2$ because the graph is shifted to the right by 2 units. But what about $\ln (3x+2)$ ? I cannot just say that the graph shifts to the left by 2 and thus the asymptote is at $x=-2$, how do I find where’s the asymptote for this graph ?

Comment: Hint: What happens when $3x+2=0$?

Comment: For $\ln(x)$, $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(x)=-\infty$, so the asymptote is $x=0$, as answer by Chris Randall below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(x)$ has an asymptote at $x= 0$, since $\ln(0)$ is undefined. So, for  what value of x is $3x+2=0$?